# Does Grails / GORM permit relationships in separate java packages?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Grails 3 application -- I've been having trouble with a hasMany property in Grails not populating. I just realized that the owning class is in a different package from the owned class. Am I doing something silly by relating across package boundaries?

Basic example of what I'm doing and observing, in case that doesn't make sense:

Owning Domain Class:

```
package com.example.project

import com.example.project.configuration.ConfigFile

class MotherClass {
    String name
    static hasMany = [ configFiles: ConfigFile ]
}
```

Owned Domain Class:

```
package com.example.project.configuration

import com.example.project.*

class ConfigFile {
    String name
    MotherClass motherClass
}
```

In Bootstrap.groovy:

```
MotherClass motherClass = new MotherClass(name:"mother").save(failOnError: true)
new ConfigFile(name: "file1", motherClass: mother).save(failOnError: true)
new ConfigFile(name: "file1", motherClass: mother).save(failOnError: true)
assert motherClass.configFiles.size() > 0 #this assertion would fail
```

In a random service:

```
assert MotherClass.findByName("mother").configFiles.size() > 0 #this would fail too.
```

My assertion fails may be caused by some other issue I'm experiencing, but I wanted to verify that crossing package boundaries wasn't to blame.

Comment: I refactored the child into the same package and the problem persists. So I'm guessing the package boundary is not the actual issue. I'll add more detail once I figure the answer out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't make a mistake in typing above, you are defining a 'motherClass' object but in ConfigFiles setting the motherClass to a 'mother' object.

I assume that's not the case - then, I think you are not providing Grails with enough information about the owner-child relationship.

Typically you would add the children to the owner class and save the owner class and let the saves cascade to children.

```
MotherClass mother = new MotherClass(name:"mother")
mother.addToConfigFiles(new ConfigFile(name: "file1", motherClass: mother))
mother.addToConfigFiles(new ConfigFile(name: "file1", motherClass: mother))
mother.save(failOnError: true)
```

And ideally you should have belongsTo clause on the ConfigFile side - otherwise the deletes won't be cascaded. see: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Comment: This seems somewhat obvious, but thank you for pointing it out. I thought saving a configFile with a reference to mother would cause GORM to add that configFile to the mother's collection. What would have to happen for GORM to essentially execute a fresh query to discover the mother's configFiles without me having to explicitly code for that? (As I understand it, it isn't querying the database to see what configFiles belong to the mother, which is why the addToConfigFiles is necessary.)

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The failure of the assertion in BootStrap.groovy makes sense because GORM populates associated, `hasMany`, sets when an entity is loaded into the Hibernate session.  But in this example, GORM won't automatically search the session and add a newly persisted entity into the `hasMany` sets of its owning entity.

Try the assertion from the other side.

```
assert ConfigFile.findAllByMotherClass(motherClass)
```

I know that doesn't solve your problem, but hopefully it points you int the right direction.

Comment: The assertion from the other side does work. I would be satisfied with that as a workaround, but there are places in the code where going backwards is awkward.